# how to find location of Id in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray data as below.

```
(
        {
        Id = "-1";
        NameEn = Country;
    },
        {
        Id = 14;
        NameEn = Iran;
    },
        {
        Id = 11;
        NameEn = Jordan;
    },
        {
        Id = 5;
        NameEn = "United Arab Emirates";
    },
        {
        Id = 4;
        NameEn = "Suadi Arabia";
    },
        {
        Id = 3;
        NameEn = Kuwait;
    },
        {
        Id = 10;
        NameEn = Yemen;
    },
        {
        Id = 6;
        NameEn = Oman;
    },
        {
        Id = 12;
        NameEn = Syria;
    },
        {
        Id = 7;
        NameEn = Qatar;
    },
        {
        Id = 13;
        NameEn = Lebanon;
    },
        {
        Id = 1;
        NameEn = Egypt;
    },
        {
        Id = 8;
        NameEn = "Bahrain Kingdom";
    }
)
```

I want to find the location where Id=5.

Any idea how can I do?

I tried with below.

```
NSString *myCountry = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"mCountryId"];
NSUInteger indexOfTheObject = [feedsCountry indexOfObject: myCountry];
NSLog(@"indexOfTheObject===%i==%@", indexOfTheObject, myCountry);

if (NSNotFound == indexOfTheObject) {
    NSLog(@"not found...");
}
```

But I get output as `not found...` for mCountryId as 5.

Comment: if any the answer accept them which will be helpful for others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `NSDictionary` instead, and key your entries by Id; e.g.:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

[dictionary setObject:@"Egypt" forKey:@"1"];
// (etc...)
```

**EDIT:** If you already have an array and can not change that, use a `for` loop like this:

```
for(NSDictionary* entry in givenArray){

    NSString* key = [entry objectForKey:@"Id"];
    NSString* value = [entry objectForKey:@"NameEn"];

    [dictionary setObject:value forKey:key];
}
```

Comment: Planning your data structures is equally, if not more important than planning your program logic.  +1

Answer (score 2):

```
NSPredicate * filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Id = 5"];
NSArray * filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

The first object in `filtered` is the dictionary with `Id = 5`